Branching control in SCIP via Pyomo
I'm working on a "hard" scheduling problem that is currently written in Pyomo, and I'm using SCIP as the solver.
Since I know the structure of the problem, I understand that branching on some specific variables will help the algorithm converge faster. However, so far, I haven't found how to specify a priority for certain variables when using Pyomo as an interface for SCIP.
How can I do this?
